# Extra vertical space before displayed math in enumeration with newtxmath

Tags: math-mode, enumerate, newtx, newtxmath

When enumerating some equations and using the [`newtxmath`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/newtx) package, extra vertical space appears before the enumerated items, as can be seen below:

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}

\usepackage[papersize={6cm,6cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{newtxmath}

\begin{document}

Evaluate the following mathematical expressions in Scilab:
\begin{enumerate}
  \item \[ \frac{4}{3}\pi \sin{x^2 - 1} \]
  \item \[ \frac{x^2 y^3}{(x - y)^2} \]
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image: displayed math in enumeration with newtxmath]

Without the `newtxmath` package, the output is:

[image: displayed math in enumeration without newtxmath]

How can this extra vertical space be suppressed when the `newtxmath` is used?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`newtxmath` loads `amsmath` and it is the AMS definition of `\[` that gives the line break.
`\[` is a display setting so a line break is really the expected layout (even though you do not get it by default with the standard `fleqn` implementation.

For the layout you want a more natural markup would be

```
\item $\displaystyle ..... $
```